# How to use regex in react

Tags: regex

I have a URL like this

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.swiggy.android&hl=en_IN&gl=US
```

So here you can see there is a parameter called id. I need to get the value of id (value after id=)and (it stops at &)

So ideal output should look like this in.swiggy.android.

I wrote regex like this but my output looks like this

id=in.swiggy.android. Here I don't need "id=" in the output. As you can see it stop just before &. So 2nd part is working fine.

```
let regex = /id=([^&]*)/;
 let value  = (regex.exec((url))[0]);``
```

Comment: What is the format for the url? Always in.swiggy?

Comment: So the value of paramater id.

Comment: Please add more details to your question. I don't understand what you want exactly.

Comment: Please see if this is okay. Added more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost reached the goal.
Actually either you have to enclose `id=` into [Positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) so your regexp turns into [`(?<=id=)([^&]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/7nEulG/1)
or just retrive 1st `[1]` element of `match` result instead of `[0]`.

```js
let regex = /id=([^&]*)/;  
let value  = (regex.exec((url))[1]);
```

Second approach works fine as well because you captured `[^&]*` into parentheses so it can be got as separate value.